# appendTo based on title and type

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, sorting, jquery-ui

I need to sort the songs based on the series title and type of the song.

I'm using jQuery UI Menu:

```
<ul id="menu"></ul>

for(y = 0; y<tytuly.length; y++){
    $('<li><div>'+tytuly[y]+'</div><ul><li><div>Openingi</div><ul id="ops'+y+'"></ul></li><li><div>Endingi</div><ul id="eds'+y+'"></ul></li><li><div>Inserty</div><ul id="ins'+y+'"></ul></li></ul></li>').appendTo('#menu');
}
```

[image: Full structure of menu]

I load content using Ajax (Example Data): `[{"nr_wpisu":"1","id":"39","typ":"1","link":"https:\/\/animethemes.moe\/video\/KakumeikiValvrave-OP1.webm","tytul_autor":"Preserved Roses","tytul":"Kakumeiki Valvrave"},{"nr_wpisu":"43","id_anime":"36","typ":"2","link":"https:\/\/animethemes.moe\/video\/MaouGakuinNoFutekigousha-ED1.webm","tytul_autor":"Hamidashimono - Tomori Kusunoki","tytul":"Maou Gakuin no Futekigousha: Shijou Saikyou no Maou no Shiso, Tensei shite Shison-tachi no Gakkou e"}]`

In the content loaded there are few records with the same title id, so I made an array without copies
Then I have the list of songs, that I have to sort by the title/title_id and their type, then append it to the correct `<ul>`

Earlier I was using:

```js
var tytuly = ["title","title2","title3","title4","title5","title6","title7","title8","title9"]; 
for(y = 0; y<tytuly.length; y++){
$('<li><div>'+tytuly[y]+'</div><ul><li><div>Openingi</div><ul id="ops'+y+'"></ul></li><li><div>Endingi</div><ul id="eds'+y+'"></ul></li><li><div>Inserty</div><ul id="ins'+y+'"></ul></li></ul></li>').appendTo('#menu');
            }
                $(function(){
        $("#menu").menu();
      });
     
      var unflist = [];
      var link = ["link","link","link","link","link","link","link","link","link"];
    var type = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1];
    var tyt_art = ["test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test"];
    for (q = 0; q <= 8; q++) {
      if (type[q] == 1) {
        $('<li class="op' + q + '"></li>').appendTo('body #ops');
        $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[q]).appendTo('body .op' + q);
      }
      if (type[q] == 2) {
        $('<li class="ed' + q + '"></li>').appendTo('body #eds');
        $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[q]).appendTo('body .ed' + q);
      }
      if (type[q] == 3) {
        $('<li class="ins' + q + '"></li>').appendTo('body #ins');
        $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[q]).appendTo('body .ins' + q);
      }
      unflist.push(link[q]);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2dQB.png)

But the sorting at this moment is not working correctly.
[enter image description here][3]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to it to make a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan done

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The example you have provided is not clear. Where is the data you are trying to Sort by title and type. Why not have your Data Source perform the grouping and sorting before providing it to your AJAX Request?

Comment: I dont know how to do that, this way was easier to me.

Comment: @Twisty Now it should be enough?

Comment: Now after a break, I think it should loop, if find equal value, get into another loop, loop all of the records from the equal value, then continue with next title, but Im not sure how im supposed to do that.

Comment: @Nurarihyon I see the update. This is a list of Titles that's already in order. Where are the Types? Please provide a proper example of the data you are working with.

Comment: @Twisty The types was the "typ" variable.
I changed it right now to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im posting the answer, maybe someone would need it someday:

```
 var currentTitleNumber;
        var q;
        for(q = 0; q<tytuly.length;q++){
    
     if(q == $.inArray(tytuly[q], tytuly)){
      currentTitleNumber = q;
    for(o = 0; o <=ostlength; o++){
      if(typ[o] == 1 && allTytuly[o] == tytuly[q]){
             $('<li class="op'+o+'"></li>').appendTo('body #ops'+currentTitleNumber);
             $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[o]).appendTo('body .op'+o);
           }
           if(typ[o] == 2 && allTytuly[o] == tytuly[q]){
             $('<li class="ed'+o+'"></li>').appendTo('body #eds'+currentTitleNumber);
             $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[o]).appendTo('body .ed'+o);
           }
           if(typ[o] == 3 && allTytuly[o] == tytuly[q]){
             $('<li class="ins'+o+'"></li>').appendTo('body #ins'+currentTitleNumber);
             $('<div/>').text(tyt_art[o]).appendTo('body .ins'+o);
           }
           
    }
    
     }
              
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have 4 arrays with no relationship:

```
var tytuly = ["title","title2","title3","title4","title5","title6","title7","title8","title9"]; 
var link = ["link","link","link","link","link","link","link","link","link"];
var type = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1];
var tyt_art = ["test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test","test"];
```

This is not advised. I would advise adjusting this to an Array of Objects.

```
var ty = [{
  title: "title 1",
  link: "link 1",
  type: 1,
  art: "test 1"
},{
  title: "title 2",
  link: "link 2",
  type: 1,
  art: "test 2"
},{
  title: "title 3",
  link: "link 3",
  type: 2,
  art: "test 3"
},{
  title: "title 4",
  link: "link 4",
  type: 2,
  art: "test 4"
},{
  title: "title 5",
  link: "link 5",
  type: 2,
  art: "test 5"
},{
  title: "title 6",
  link: "link 6",
  type: 3,
  art: "test 6"
},{
  title: "title 7",
  link: "link 7",
  type: 3,
  art: "test 7"
},{
  title: "title 8",
  link: "link 8",
  type: 1,
  art: "test 8"
},{
  title: "title 9",
  link: "link 9",
  type: 1,
  art: "test 9"
}];
```

With your data arranged like this, you can more easily use it. If you want to sort by a specific type, you can do this with `.sort()` using a Compare Function.

```js
var ty = [{
    title: "title 1",
    link: "link 1",
    type: "1",
    art: "test 1"
  }, {
    title: "title 2",
    link: "link 2",
    type: "1",
    art: "test 2"
  }, {
    title: "title 3",
    link: "link 3",
    type: "2",
    art: "test 3"
  }, {
    title: "title 4",
    link: "link 4",
    type: "2",
    art: "test 4"
  }, {
    "nr_wpisu": "1",
    "id": "39",
    "type": "1",
    "link": "https:\/\/animethemes.moe\/video\/KakumeikiValvrave-OP1.webm",
    art: "Preserved Roses",
    title: "Kakumeiki Valvrave"
  }, {
    "nr_wpisu": "43",
    "id_anime": "36",
    "type": "2",
    "link": "https:\/\/animethemes.moe\/video\/MaouGakuinNoFutekigousha-ED1.webm",
    art: "Hamidashimono - Tomori Kusunoki",
    title: "Maou Gakuin no Futekigousha: Shijou Saikyou no Maou no Shiso, Tensei shite Shison-tachi no Gakkou e"
  }, {
    title: "title 7",
    link: "link 7",
    type: "3",
    art: "test 7"
  },
  {
    title: "title 8",
    link: "link 8",
    type: "1",
    art: "test 8"
  }, {
    title: "title 9",
    link: "link 9",
    type: "1",
    art: "test 9"
  }, {
    title: "Song 1",
    link: "link 10",
    type: null,
    art: "Test 10"
  }
];

function popMenu(tObj, myData) {
  var op = $("<li>").html("<div>Openingi</div>").appendTo(tObj);
  $("<ul>", {
    id: "op"
  }).insertAfter($("div", op));
  var ed = $("<li>").html("<div>Endingi</div>").appendTo(tObj);
  $("<ul>", {
    id: "ed"
  }).insertAfter($("div", ed));
  var ins = $("<li>").html("<div>Inserty</div>").appendTo(tObj);
  $("<ul>", {
    id: "ins"
  }).insertAfter($("div", ins));
  $.each(myData, function(i, t) {
    switch (t.type) {
      case "1":
        $('<li>', {
          class: "op-" + i
        }).appendTo($("ul", op));
        $('<div>', {
          title: t.art
        }).text(t.title).appendTo($('.op-' + i, tObj));
        break;
      case "2":
        $('<li>', {
          class: "ed-" + i
        }).appendTo($("ul", ed));
        $('<div>', {
          title: t.art
        }).text(t.title).appendTo($('.ed-' + i, tObj));
        break;
      case "3":
        $('<li>', {
          class: "ins-" + i
        }).appendTo($("ul", ins));
        $('<div>', {
          title: t.art
        }).text(t.title).appendTo($('.ins-' + i, tObj));
        break;
      default:
        var s = $('<li>').appendTo(tObj);
        $('<div>', {
          title: t.art
        }).text(t.title).appendTo(s);
    }
  });
}


$(function() {
  popMenu($("#menu"), ty);
  $("#menu").menu();
});
```

```css
#menu {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

Reference Links:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I mean, I got an JSON Array looking like an object loaded from PHP using Ajax, I gave an data example above.
The way u did it, it just sorts out the title, there are no subsection for the "Openingi", "Endingi", "Inserty", and another subsections for the songs.

Comment: @Nurarihyon the relationship was unclear based on your OP. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Almost, but still not enough. The first section is for the series titles, then each title has 3 subsections which are: "Openingi", "Endingi" and "Inserty" and each of these subsections contains songs based on series title and song type.

Comment: @Nurarihyon you should be able to adjust my example for your needs at this point. If you really need more help, go back and Edit your OP and maybe show an image screen shot of what you want the end result to look like. You may also want to review: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Okay, I managed to do it my way somehow, thank you for your try to help me, and sorry for your wasted time :/